# Unable to create or access file at path: /storage/self/primary/Download/ from native-lib.cpp in android studio

Tags: javascript, android, c++, file, java-native-interface

In one of my project it requires me to create/read/write file at path /storage/self/primary/Download/ from .cpp file in android studio,but I'm unable to access to that path.

As of now I am able to pass the path: /storage/self/primary/Download/ from MainActivity.java to native-lib.cpp

Android Studio Default Configuration
minSdk = 29
targetSdk = 34

Below code is to pass the path: /storage/self/primary/Download/ from MainActivity.java with below code
to native-lib.cpp

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
String str = path.toString();
typLog.d("path",path.toString());
stringFromJNI(str); //Calling APIe here
```

the path received in native-lib.cpp is same as sent.

But after this I'm not able to access that path to create/read/write to file in that folder.

PS: I've already tried with below method but still not able to access it.

```
std::ofstream fp;
fp.open("/storage/self/primary/Download/sample.txt",std::ios::out);
if(fp.is_open()){
   fp << "hello world";
   fp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- The changes in Android 10 (API level 29) and later. The scoped storage feature introduced in Android 10 restricts apps from accessing files outside their app-specific directory.
- To access the Download directory, you need to request the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file4

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- Then, in your MainActivity.java file, request the permissions at runtime

  ```
  private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 10;
  private static final String[] REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"};

  private void requestPermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS[0]) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS[1])) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Permission needed")
                .setMessage("This permission is needed because of this and that")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create()
                .show();
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS[0]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || checkSelfPermission(REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS[1]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }
  }
  ```